# how retrieve metadata from shoutcast on android?

Tags: android, metadata

I am developing a player that plays a url of the form
shoucast http://292.3.23.23:8000 is, as I can restore the
metadata? artist name mediaplayer use the title etc.
play no problem, but I can not retrieve metadata
anyone know how I can do it and display it in a text
titulo.settext (title);

Answer (score 7):

check this out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html but it is on API LEVEL 10

Thank you.

I have done using the thread,not the great solution but it works

```
public class IcyStreamMeta {

protected URL streamUrl;
private Map<String, String> metadata;
private boolean isError;

public IcyStreamMeta(URL streamUrl) {
    setStreamUrl(streamUrl);

    isError = false;
}

/**
 * Get artist using stream's title
 *
 * @return String
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String getArtist() throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> data = getMetadata();

    if (!data.containsKey("StreamTitle"))
        return "";

    String streamTitle = data.get("StreamTitle");
    String title = streamTitle.substring(0, streamTitle.indexOf("-"));
    return title.trim();
}

/**
 * Get title using stream's title
 *
 * @return String
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String getTitle() throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> data = getMetadata();

    if (!data.containsKey("StreamTitle"))
        return "";

    String streamTitle = data.get("StreamTitle");
    String artist = streamTitle.substring(streamTitle.indexOf("-")+1);
    return artist.trim();
}

public Map<String, String> getMetadata() throws IOException {
    if (metadata == null) {
        refreshMeta();
    }

    return metadata;
}

public void refreshMeta() throws IOException {
    retreiveMetadata();
}

private void retreiveMetadata() throws IOException {
    URLConnection con = streamUrl.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("Icy-MetaData", "1");
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", null);
    con.connect();

    int metaDataOffset = 0;
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = con.getHeaderFields();
    InputStream stream = con.getInputStream();

    if (headers.containsKey("icy-metaint")) {
        // Headers are sent via HTTP
        metaDataOffset = Integer.parseInt(headers.get("icy-metaint").get(0));
    } else {
        // Headers are sent within a stream
        StringBuilder strHeaders = new StringBuilder();
        char c;
        while ((c = (char)stream.read()) != -1) {
            strHeaders.append(c);
            if (strHeaders.length() > 5 && (strHeaders.substring((strHeaders.length() - 4), strHeaders.length()).equals("\r\n\r\n"))) {
                // end of headers
                break;
            }
        }

        // Match headers to get metadata offset within a stream
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\r\\n(icy-metaint):\\s*(.*)\\r\\n");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(strHeaders.toString());
        if (m.find()) {
            metaDataOffset = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
        }
    }

    // In case no data was sent
    if (metaDataOffset == 0) {
        isError = true;
        return;
    }

    // Read metadata
    int b;
    int count = 0;
    int metaDataLength = 4080; // 4080 is the max length
    boolean inData = false;
    StringBuilder metaData = new StringBuilder();
    // Stream position should be either at the beginning or right after headers
    while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
        count++;

        // Length of the metadata
        if (count == metaDataOffset + 1) {
            metaDataLength = b * 16;
        }

        if (count > metaDataOffset + 1 && count < (metaDataOffset + metaDataLength)) {              
            inData = true;
        } else {                
            inData = false;             
        }               
        if (inData) {               
            if (b != 0) {                   
                metaData.append((char)b);               
            }           
        }               
        if (count > (metaDataOffset + metaDataLength)) {
            break;
        }

    }

    // Set the data
    metadata = IcyStreamMeta.parseMetadata(metaData.toString());

    // Close
    stream.close();
}

public boolean isError() {
    return isError;
}

public URL getStreamUrl() {
    return streamUrl;
}

public void setStreamUrl(URL streamUrl) {
    this.metadata = null;
    this.streamUrl = streamUrl;
    this.isError = false;
}

public static Map<String, String> parseMetadata(String metaString) {
    Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap();
    String[] metaParts = metaString.split(";");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+)=\\'([^\\']*)\\'$");
    Matcher m;
    for (int i = 0; i < metaParts.length; i++) {
        m = p.matcher(metaParts[i]);
        if (m.find()) {
            metadata.put((String)m.group(1), (String)m.group(2));
        }
    }

    return metadata;
}
```

}

make thread call each 10 sec

```
public void startThread(){

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

            URL url;
            Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
            try {
                url = new URL(URL);
                  IcyStreamMeta icy = new IcyStreamMeta(url);

                    Log.d("SONG",icy.getTitle());
                  msg.obj = icy.getTitle();

                Log.d("ARTITSi",icy.getArtist());
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, 0, 10000);

}
```

Comment: -1 for not mentioning that this code is not yours. http://uniqueculture.net/2010/11/stream-metadata-plain-java/