# Get online radio song details in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, internet-radio

I have to stream and play a third party radio station in my Android app. 
Here is my code to do so and it works well.

```
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(RADIO_STATION_URL);
        try {
            this.mp = new MediaPlayer();

            mp.setDataSource(this, myUri);
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mp.prepareAsync();
            mp.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            logcat t details
        }
```

and starting the mediaplayer when the media file is ready for playback. Is there any way to get currently playing song details too? (like song, track names etc).

Comment: does the server have the details of the song track name etc. if so you can retrieve the same. If its in the response header you can get the content and description from the response header

Comment: have u tried [Query MP3 Information using Android supported function](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/tag/mp3/)  ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using API 10 or more, you can use the [MediaMetadataRetriver API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html).

It would be something like this :

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mMediaMetaDataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mMediaMetaDataRetriever.setDataSource(myContext, myUri)
String albumName =  mMediaMetaDataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM;
String artistName =  mMediaMetaDataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST;
String titleName = mMediaMetaDataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

May you can have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638251/how-retrieve-metadata-from-shoutcast-on-android) too.