# Get the icy-meta using the android.media.Extractor

Tags: android, shoutcast, internet-radio, mediaextractor

Is it possible to get the icy-meta from streaming data using [android.media.MediaExtractor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html)?

I want to get the artist and title.

Comment: Yup, you can get meta data of any channel before start streaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android's `MediaExtractor` does not demux SHOUTcast-style ICY metadata.  You will have to [request it and demux it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6638251/362536) before decoding the audio data.

Additionally, the metadata does not specify fields.  There is only `StreamTitle` and `StreamURL`.  The `StreamTitle` field is usually in the format of `Artist - Title`, but not always.  It is up to the station to determine the format of that field.

The `StreamURL` is generally left blank, and doesn't typically exist in the case of Icecast streams.

Comment: I does't use MediaExtractor. I used InputStream,  but I can't MediaCodec to byte Array. How decode byte Array?
I maked new **[question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029342/android-decode-mp3-with-mediacodec-not-use-mediaextractor)**.