# Android decode mp3 with MediaCodec. not use MediaExtractor

Tags: java, android, mp3, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I want to decode the mp3 using the MediaCodec.
However, I do not want to use the MediaExtractor.
Because it is because I want to get the meta data from mp3.
icy (Shoutcast) stream are also taken into consideration.

I tried writing the code to decode the mp3 files from FileInputStream by improving the [sample](https://github.com/ytRino/MediaCodecSample/blob/a65e7b73ea299fda6d3f4ff66edc1c362986b70d/src/net/nessness/android/sample/showmycodec/MainActivity.java) of MediaExtractor. However decode caused the error is not possible.

```java
 

    package com.test;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.AudioFormat;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.AudioTrack;
    import android.media.MediaCodec;
    import android.media.MediaCodec.BufferInfo;

    import android.media.MediaFormat;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

    import com.test.R;

    public class AndroidTestActivity extends Activity {

        private static final String TAG = "TAG";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        process();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }

        private synchronized void process() throws IOException {



            File inputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/download/music/test.mp3");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);        


            MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat("audio/mpeg", 44100,2);
            String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
            //int sampleRate = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE);


            MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
            codec.configure(format, null , null , 0);
            codec.start();


            ByteBuffer[] codecInputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();
            ByteBuffer[] codecOutputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();



            AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE),
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    8000, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            track.play();

            BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();
            boolean inputEos = false;
            boolean outputEos = false;
            long timeoutUs = 1000;

            byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[8192];

            while (!outputEos) {

                if (!inputEos) {

                    int inputBufIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(timeoutUs);
                    if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {

                        ByteBuffer buf = codecInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];


                        int bytesRead = fis.read(tempBuffer, 0, buf.limit());

                        long presentationTimeUs = 0;
                        if (bytesRead = 0) {

                    int outputBufIndex = res;

                    ByteBuffer buf = codecOutputBuffers[outputBufIndex];
                    byte[] dst = new byte[info.size];
                    int oldPosition = buf.position();

                    buf.get(dst);
                    buf.position(oldPosition);

                    //Play music
                    track.write(dst, 0, dst.length);

                    codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufIndex, false);

                    if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "output eos.");
                        outputEos = true;
                    }
                } else if (res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "output buffer changed.");
                    codecOutputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();
                } else if (res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                    MediaFormat f = codec.getOutputFormat();
                    Log.d(TAG, "output format changed. " + f);
                    //track.setPlaybackRate(f.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE));
                }
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "complete stop!");
            fis.close();
            codec.stop();
            codec.release();
        }


    }
```

Error during execution...

```java
 

    01-20 00:57:20.436: I/System.out(2626): Sending WAIT chunk
    01-20 00:57:20.436: W/ActivityThread(2626): Application com.test is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
    01-20 00:57:20.446: I/dalvikvm(2626): Debugger is active
    01-20 00:57:20.636: I/System.out(2626): Debugger has connected
    01-20 00:57:20.636: I/System.out(2626): waiting for debugger to settle...
    01-20 00:57:20.836: I/System.out(2626): waiting for debugger to settle...
    01-20 00:57:21.036: I/System.out(2626): waiting for debugger to settle...
    01-20 00:57:21.236: I/System.out(2626): waiting for debugger to settle...
    01-20 00:57:21.441: I/System.out(2626): waiting for debugger to settle...
    01-20 00:57:21.641: I/System.out(2626): waiting for debugger to settle...
    01-20 00:57:21.846: I/System.out(2626): waiting for debugger to settle...
    01-20 00:57:22.046: I/System.out(2626): debugger has settled (1443)
    01-20 00:57:22.271: I/OMXClient(2626): Using client-side OMX mux.
    01-20 00:57:22.276: E/SEC_COMP_REGS(2626): .
    01-20 00:57:22.276: E/SEC_COMP_REGS(2626): ..
    01-20 00:57:22.276: E/SEC_COMP_REGS(2626): libOMX.SEC.AVC.Decoder.so
    01-20 00:57:22.276: E/SEC_COMP_REGS(2626): Path & libName : /system/lib/omx/libOMX.SEC.AVC.Decoder.so
    01-20 00:57:22.276: E/SEC_COMP_REGS(2626): libOMX.SEC.AVC.Encoder.so
    01-20 00:57:22.276: E/SEC_COMP_REGS(2626): Path & libName : /system/lib/omx/libOMX.SEC.AVC.Encoder.so
    01-20 00:57:22.281: E/SEC_COMP_REGS(2626): libOMX.SEC.M4V.Decoder.so
    01-20 00:57:22.281: E/SEC_COMP_REGS(2626): Path & libName : /system/lib/omx/libOMX.SEC.M4V.Decoder.so
    01-20 00:57:22.281: E/SEC_COMP_REGS(2626): libOMX.SEC.M4V.Encoder.so
    01-20 00:57:22.291: E/SEC_COMP_REGS(2626): Path & libName : /system/lib/omx/libOMX.SEC.M4V.Encoder.so
    01-20 00:57:22.291: E/SEC_COMP_REGS(2626): libOMX.SEC.WMV.Decoder.so
    01-20 00:57:22.291: E/SEC_COMP_REGS(2626): Path & libName : /system/lib/omx/libOMX.SEC.WMV.Decoder.so
    01-20 00:57:22.311: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.321: D/TAG(2626): output format changed. {sample-rate=44100, channel-count=2, what=1869968451, mime=audio/raw}
    01-20 00:57:22.331: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.341: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.351: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.396: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.436: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.481: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.486: D/libEGL(2626): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
    01-20 00:57:22.491: D/libEGL(2626): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
    01-20 00:57:22.496: D/libEGL(2626): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
    01-20 00:57:22.506: E/(2626): Device driver API match
    01-20 00:57:22.506: E/(2626): Device driver API version: 23
    01-20 00:57:22.506: E/(2626): User space API version: 23 
    01-20 00:57:22.506: E/(2626): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57 KST 2013 
    01-20 00:57:22.526: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.536: D/OpenGLRenderer(2626): Enabling debug mode 0
    01-20 00:57:22.576: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.621: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.626: I/ActivityManager(2626): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@424d6780 time:611732103
    01-20 00:57:22.666: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.716: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.811: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.856: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.901: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.951: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:22.996: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.041: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.091: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.136: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.226: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.276: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.321: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.366: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.416: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.461: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.506: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.551: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.656: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.691: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.741: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.786: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.831: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.876: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.926: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:23.976: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.066: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.111: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.156: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.201: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.256: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.296: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.341: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.386: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.481: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.526: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.576: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.621: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.666: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.711: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.756: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.801: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.896: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.941: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:24.986: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.036: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.081: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.126: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.176: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.221: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.316: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.361: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.411: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.456: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.501: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.546: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.596: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.641: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.736: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.781: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.831: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.876: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.921: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:25.966: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.016: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.061: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.151: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.201: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.246: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.296: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.336: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.386: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.436: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.476: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.571: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.621: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.666: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.711: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.756: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.831: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.876: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.911: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:26.986: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.031: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.076: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.126: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.176: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.221: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.266: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.311: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.406: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.451: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.501: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.551: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.591: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.636: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.686: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.731: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.826: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.871: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.916: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:27.966: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.011: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.056: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.101: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.151: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.241: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.291: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.336: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.381: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.426: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.476: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.521: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.566: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.661: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.706: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.756: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.801: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.856: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.891: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.941: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:28.986: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:29.076: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:29.126: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:29.171: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:29.221: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:29.266: E/SoftMP3(2626): mp3 decoder returned error 12
    01-20 00:57:29.401: D/TAG(2626): output eos.
    01-20 00:57:29.401: D/TAG(2626): complete stop!
    01-20 00:57:29.411: I/OMXNodeInstance(2626): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x524cc9d8 successful
    01-20 00:57:29.411: I/OMXNodeInstance(2626): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x524cc8d8 successful
    01-20 00:57:29.411: I/OMXNodeInstance(2626): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x524cc7c0 successful
    01-20 00:57:29.416: I/OMXNodeInstance(2626): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x524cad28 successful
    01-20 00:57:29.416: I/OMXNodeInstance(2626): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x524cd018 successful
    01-20 00:57:29.421: I/OMXNodeInstance(2626): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x524ccf48 successful
    01-20 00:57:29.421: I/OMXNodeInstance(2626): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x524cce30 successful
    01-20 00:57:29.426: I/OMXNodeInstance(2626): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x524cccb8 successful
```

Comment: You fill codec input buffer, but never not call codec.queueInputBuffer()!